# Square changes speed after time

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So I'm new to making games on JS and I've been following a books instructions and some questions from this site. I've managed to make a simple html canvas site which has a small square. I've got the square to not be able to leave the borders.

But my problem is that my square increases it's speed after a bit of testing so it goes from pressing right arrow 8 times for example to get from left to right to 4 times. I have been searching google trying to find an answer to no avail.

[Here is my JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jL697fa4/) (I've seen people use this here so I guess I would too);

The square doesn't appear in the fiddle (idk why) but when I stick it in webstorm it seems to work when loaded in google chrome.

Thanks in advance.

It says I need to acccompany jsfille stuff with some code so here's the start of my jsfiddle.

```
var Game = {
    canvas : undefined,
    canvasContext : undefined,
    rectanglePositionX : 50,
    rectanglePositionY: 50,

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the square is responding erratically can be found in the `Game.update()` function. Since you are adding the listener in a function that gets called 60 times per second, it adds that listener every time, which is why you had the position being altered to only 1/1000th of the actual distance it seems like you want the square to move. This can be fixed by setting up the event listener only once, outside of the game loop, since that gets called repeatedly.

Here's a working snippet with the code from your fiddle (not sure what isn't working with that), where I've dropped the `Game.update()` function completely and put all the logic from that inside the event listener. The rectangle position will now only be set once when an arrow key is pressed, though the function will run every time any key is pressed. Since the game loop is constantly rerendering the canvas, the changes show up every time.

Alternatively, you can render and draw the canvas in the event listener also (I wrote them in there and commented them out), instead of rebuilding it inside a recursive setTimeout, but I'm not sure what other game logic you are looking to implement, and maybe you need it. But for purposes of demonstration, try commenting out the `Game.mainLoop()` invocation inside `Game.start()`, and uncomment the methods at the bottom of the keydown listener.

Hopefully this helps you out.

```js
var Game = {
  canvas: undefined,
  canvasContext: undefined,
  rectanglePositionX: 50,
  rectanglePositionY: 50,
};

Game.start = function() {
  Game.canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  Game.canvasContext = Game.canvas.getContext("2d");
  // comment this out to instead invoke the clearCanvas and draw methods inside the listener:
  Game.mainLoop();
};

Game.clearCanvas = function() {
  Game.canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, Game.canvas.width,   Game.canvas.height);
};

Game.mainLoop = function() {
  Game.clearCanvas();
  Game.draw();
  window.setTimeout(Game.mainLoop, 1000 / 60);
};

Game.draw = function() {
  Game.canvasContext.fillStyle = "blue";
  Game.canvasContext.fillRect(Game.rectanglePositionX, Game.rectanglePositionY, 10, 10);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Game.start);

document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  var d = new Date();
  console.log(Game.rectanglePositionX, Game.rectanglePositionY, d);
  const key = event.key;
  if (key == "ArrowUp") {
    if (Game.rectanglePositionY > 1) {
      Game.rectanglePositionY -= 10;
    } else {
      Game.rectanglePositionY += 10;
    }
  }

  if (key == "ArrowDown") {
    if (Game.rectanglePositionY < 470) {
      Game.rectanglePositionY += 10;
    } else {
      Game.rectanglePositionY -= 10;
    }
  }

  if (key == "ArrowLeft") {
    if (Game.rectanglePositionX > 1) {
      Game.rectanglePositionX -= 10;
    } else {
      Game.rectanglePositionX += 10
    }
  }

  if (key == "ArrowRight") {
    if (Game.rectanglePositionX < 790) {
      Game.rectanglePositionX += 10;
    } else {
      Game.rectanglePositionX -= 10;
    }
  }
  // Game.clearCanvas(); 
  // Game.draw();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  border: solid 10px gold;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>MovingSquare</title>
    <script src="BasicGame.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="gameArea">
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="480"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Cheers!